# How to put a png image on a line plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to put a PNG image on a line plot, I want it to look like a watermark. Can someone walk me through it?

So far this is my code:

```
s=sns.lineplot(data=df[['eth-in','eth-out']], dashes=False,)

plt.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')

plt.xlabel("Block Signed Date",color='white')
plt.ylabel("Amount",color='white')


axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as image

im = image.imread("example.png") #read image

x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
y = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Graph Title')

fig.figimage(im, 900, 200, zorder=3, alpha=.3)  #900,200 -> x/y image offset in pixels.

plt.show()
```

[image: example]